# $adapter->query() in Zend not working - String to long for insert?

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework, zend-db

I am inserting data in Zend framework with the db adapter

```
$adapter = Zend_Db_Table::getDefaultAdapter();
```

and execute an insert statement like this:

```
$q = "INSERT INTO questions (category_id, user_id, `text`, active) 
VALUES($category_id, ".$user_id.", '".$question_text."', 1)";
$adapter->query($q);
```

However sometimes this query does not work. This only happens when `$question_text` is pretty long (>1000 chars) and does not depend on the content but only the length. Executing the same statement in phpmyadmin works without problems. (The db field is a text)

When I use

```
$adapter->exec($q);
```

the query works fine as well.

Now my questions:

**What's causing the problem for the query() statement?**

**Are there any downsides to use exec() instead?**

Comment: looks like this was/is a bug with the preg functions see the bug report that matches the symptoms you are describing http://framework.zend.com/issues/browse/ZF-8399

Comment: Are you properly escaping the input data?  Does the problem occur if you use the object oriented interface for insert?  Also what OS and ZF version are you using?  Are you checking the result of the query, and do you get any error messages or just no new data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you change the insert to use the object oriented interface which escapes your input data for you, do you still have the problem?

```
$values = array('category_id' => $category_id,
                'user_id'     => $user_id,
                'text'        => $question_text,
                'active'      => 1);

$inserted = $adapter->insert('questions', $values);
```

`$inserted` should contain the number of rows affected by the operation, 1.

Comment: i dont get @drew010, if horen wants to insert multiple records using this query then your answer is good enough? I dont think so.N problem is not escaping...problem is OS(horen must be on MAC OR WIN). Check out my answer Horen

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same error when I tried to insert a PDF into a BLOB. PHP's mysql_query() function worked fine, but the Zend functions query() or exec() just wouldn't work, although there were no error or exception thrown. This seems to be a problem known to Zend, since there are some bugs filed.

What worked for me is not the most elegant way to solve this, but it works. As mentioned above, PHP's mysql_query() worked, so I took the parameters from Zend application.ini and used them to create a new connection using PHP.

```
    <?php
    $front = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance();
    $bootstrap = $front->getParam('bootstrap');
    $options = $bootstrap->getOptions();
    $dbOptions = $options["resources"]["db"]["params"];

    $link = mysql_connect($dbOptions["host"], $dbOptions["username"], $dbOptions["password"]);
    if (!$link) {
        die('Verbindung schlug fehl: ' . mysql_error());
    }
    mysql_select_db($dbOptions["dbname"]);

    $ret = (mysql_query($query) === TRUE)? TRUE : mysql_error();

    mysql_close($link);

    return $ret;
    ?>
```

This will either return TRUE or the mysql-error.

Answer (score 1):

May be late to answer, but I have the soultion.**Thanks to @martynthewolf link**.Two solution for zend I found:

```
$db->getConnection()->query($sql); // use getConnection()

$db->exec($sql);
```

This issue is because of memory stack size. On linux the stack grows as needed, but on Windows & Mac this issue gets bubbled because of the stack size. For this there a ticket raised in php.net(here) Have a look. Enjoy!!!